# My GoogleMap application will not run and but no errors in logcat

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I try to create a basic Google map when I run this code it won't run in my phone. ...also I can't see running process error in my logcat and I changed my extends class `SupportFragmentActivity`, `MapFragmentActivity` and `Activity` all are no use it won't work?

**MainAcitivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }    }
```

**Manifest file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="googlemap.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <permission 
        android:name="google.com.permision.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="google.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data 
            />
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyDBrdz7HdE74prr0mmtGtl4nIQq8C9wBD4"/>
        <meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Main Xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Have you activated your map key with your SHA1? read here: http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/02/advance-android-google-map-2-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you retrieved a gray map on your phone? If so, your `API_KEY` for your map did not set correctly.

Please try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will finally get a map on your phone.

I see there is nothing in your `MainAcitivity`, sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private EditText et_address, et_finalAddress;
    LatLng addressPos, finalAddressPos;
    Marker addressMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        et_finalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalAddressEditText);


        // Initial Map
        try {

            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // Put a dot on my current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        // 3D building
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        // Get zoom button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(goodLatLng)
                .title("Hello"));
    }
```

For more details, please refer to my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bjiang/map_ex/MainActivity.java).

Comment: Thank you so much for your video tutorial suggestion  i achieve my task :)

Answer (score 1):

Your **`XML`**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/iqamah_map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Your Java Class

```
 public class YourActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
        map =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.iqamah_map)).getMap();

    }
}
```